# Запустить файл из консоли как PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, консоль

Есть файлик без расширения, именуемый `testfile`, с содержимым:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

echo 1111;
```

На текущий момент, если я пишу

`testfile`

то получаю ошибку:

> testfile: command not found

Если пишу

`php testfile`

то всё хорошо.

Я хочу писать в консоли `testfile` и чтобы он исполнялся интерпретатором php. Я думал, что директива `#!/usr/bin/env php` должна делать задуманное, но нет.

Comment: Право на исполнение добавьте.

Comment: `chmod +x testfile` и запуск `./testfile`

Comment: @u_mulder что-то не помогает. У меня даже 777 стоит

Comment: `./testfile` или поместить по путям, известным по `$PATH`

Comment: @u_mulder `./testfile` --- вот так начало работать. Правда только `echo`. если использую `require_once` в пхп - то ноль эмоций. Наверное с этим разберусь

Comment: @u_mulder в общем всё, свое тоже починил.. Действительно достаточно писать `./testfile`

Comment: Раз вы все починили - то можете написать ответ. Чтобы другие люди с подобной проблемой могли все починить.

Comment: @u_mulder я не знаю почему работает `./testfile`, но не работает `testfile`. Потому что первое - попытка исполнить файл, а второе - внутреннюю команду убунту? Если это кто-то бы описал - тогда это потянуло бы на ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы запускать в консоли какой-то файл на исполнение, надо, во-первых, дать этому файлу право на исполнение:

```
chmod +x testfile
```

Далее, разберемся в чем разница между `./testfile` и `testfile`.

`./testfile` сообщает что "В текущей директории (так как `.` это обозначение текущей директории) найди файл testfile и запусти его"

`testfile` сообщает что "Найди файл testfile и запусти его". Естественно, поиск файла `testfile` по всему диску/дискам может затянуться, поэтому существует специальное ограничение - поиск ведется по путям, обозначенным в переменной `PATH`.

Ее значение можно получить например так:

```
> echo $PATH
```

Выведется нечто вроде

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
```

Здесь каждое значение между `:` обозначает путь, где система попытается найти ваш файл. Таким образом, можно, например, поместить `testfile` в каталог `/usr/local/bin` и свободно запускать теперь `testfile`, так как система его найдет. Вторым вариантом является модификация переменной `$PATH` и добавление туда вашего пути, чтобы система могла поискать исполняемый файл и в нем.

Comment: Теперь я хоть знаю в чем отличие и как лечить.  Благодарю.